# Ошибка 403 при обращении запроса nginx

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

Не могу настроить nginx на запрос /static/, работает в паре с gunicorn и django. Как ни настраивай, ошибка 403 Forbidden.

Конфиг файл nginx в папке sites-enabled настраиваю правильно:

```
server {

    server_name <имя сайта>;

    location /.well-known {
    root /var/www/html;
    }

    location /static/ {
        root /home/betepok/yukiteru_test/betepoksite/yukiteru_testing;
    }

    ...
```

Ниже папка, до которой пытаюсь добраться.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Смотреть в error.log. Скорее всего не хватает прав на какой-то каталог выше

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Измените root добавив static в конце:

```
root /home/betepok/yukiteru_test/betepoksite/yukiteru_testing/static;
```

Удостоверьтесь что у пользователя (группы) под которыми работае Nginx есть права.

Команда `nginx -T` покажет вам конфиг. Вас должна интересовать директива `user`.

Comment: Помогло одно. Теперь nginx работает от моего пользователя, хотя у пользователя www-data, что стоял до этого, судя по команде sudo find / -user www-data, были все права к папке static.
И в пути конфига, добавление /static/ не нужно, сервер начинает искать файлы в папке /static/static, которой разумеется нет.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте ко всем файлам вашего проекта установить права 644, а к каталогам 755

Comment: Не помогало. Ради интереса даже прописывал всем 777, но проблема оставалась.